# Adobe Air desktop to read Unity standard output

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, unity-game-engine, air

I am working on some Air Desktop application with in some part runs another application built with unity3d as a native process

```
var processArgs:Vector.<String > = new Vector.<String>();
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("bin");
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("bin/unityApp.exe");

var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS, onOutputData);
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);

process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes(processArgs + "\n");



function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("Got: ", process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
}

function onErrorData(event: ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable));

}

function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
{
    trace("Process exited with ", event.exitCode);
}

function onIOError(event: IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(event.toString());
}
```

and in the unity app there is a button which is supposed to send a standard output so i can read it in Air.
my problem is that i used c# methods in unity to send the output but never read in air i used

```
Debug.log("text");
System.Console.Write("text");
System.Console.WriteLine("text");
```

i am new to unity and c# so i am asking what function should i use in unity to send standard output that Air can read
thanks.

Comment: Away from Unity, just using a C# coded `.exe` are you able to send **stdout** and receive that text inside AIR? Are you sure that Unity can allow **stdin/out** with other programs? Anyways.. If possible provide a very basic testable `.exe` (Unity made) that when clicked sends output ( to **standard output**) for any listening process to read. Maybe can test for you?

Comment: That is exactly the problem, that no one is telling if unity is sending standard output, so i am asking if there is a way in unity to do that.
i created a simple app with just a button to send text to log or system console with the functions i mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To AIR app add startup arguments:

```
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments[0] = "-nolog";
```

In Unity add this code that sends some string to console:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter standardOutput = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.Console.OpenStandardOutput());
standardOutput.Write("Hello!");
standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
System.Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try it and tell if it works